# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable while running Correto Docker image in AWS ECS

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, amazon-ecs

I am working on Spring boot application where I trying to deploy it on AWS ECS, Before that I tried it on local (Docker Desktop) where it is working fine but same correto8 image is giving below mentioned error on AWS ECS.

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable`

This is the Docker file that I am using:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:8

# Copy your WAR file to the Tomcat webapps directory
WORKDIR /
COPY target/spring-boot-app*.war app.war

# Expose the default Tomcat port (8080)
 EXPOSE 8080

ARG PROFILE
ENV PROFILE=${PROFILE}
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/jre

RUN chown 1000 app.war
RUN /bin/bash -c echo ${PROFILE}
USER 1000

CMD java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test -DskipTests /app.war
```

I guess this is related to maven classpath issue.

Comment: Are you sure the docker image you are running on ECS is exactly the same as the docker image you are running locally? Assuming you are storing the image in ECR, did you download that exact image from ECR to your local computer and test it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a version conflict issue that is not defined in the pom.xml file.
This appears to be something that can happen if the version of the library referenced by the library being referenced in the project is not specified.